# Как сделать частичную копию базы данных Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть база на Oracle 10g, ее полный размер - 1,3 Тб, при том что как минимум 1Тб - pdf документы - картинки,
которые не несут смысловой нагрузки. Как можно сделать частичную копию, при том что я точно знаю из каких таблиц я хочу исключить данные ?

Comment: Снять дамп с перечнем таблиц, которые вам необходимы. К примеру так `exp user/pass file=/mypath/my.dmp tables=user.TABLE_A,user.TABLE_B

Comment: Уточню - я не волшебник, я только учусь. Таблиц огромная куча, а ненужных только 2 штуки. Что мне даст дамп ?

Comment: Дамп снимет вам копию БД полностью. Потом можно будет его же анналогичной утилитой залить на другую БД. Есть возможность и исключать таблицы. По факту и будет это вашей частичной копией. Почитайте информацию по утилитам exp, imp. А также Data Pump Import и Data Pump Export

Comment: Наткнулся на другой вопрос. Нет у меня столько памяти свободной что бы сделать полный дамп. И после совета с коллегами выяснил, что вообще не переносить таблицы нельзя, нужно их создать но без данных.

Comment: Без проблем. Помоему параметр rows=n. т.е. `exp user/pass file=/mypath/my.dmp tables=user.TABLE_A,user.TABLE_B rows=n`. будет только структура, без данных

Comment: Есть возможность связать базы через линк?

Comment: Есть. А как это мне поможет ?

Comment: @duber.fm дампом забираете структуру и если нет возможности дампом же забрать данные, то просто перетаскиваете все необходимые данные по сети через линк. Это займет конечно некоторое время, но если операция разовая, то можно и подождать.

Comment: Почему не подходит `expdp ... exclude=table:"IN('TAB2','TAB1')"`?

Comment: Исключать таблицы нельзя - помимо ненужных pdf есть еще и нужные данные, которые почти не занимают места.

Comment: Так можно и поля исключить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено следующим образом - сделали полную копию, убили blob-ы документов, остаток перенесли в другой tablespace и зачистили пустышки. Не тот вариант что хотел, но другого не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

```
RMAN:

SKIP [FOREVER]
   TABLESPACE
   tablespace_name
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta2008.htm#RCMRF149

Comment: Как я понимаю, это подходит в случае, если бы данные этих таблиц были в отдельном TABLESPACE. А если в нем есть и другие данные, которые мне важны ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать с параметром [remap_data](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-B831E91E-E720-4492-B9FD-E5DA78CC3E36).
В примере ограничился одной таблицей, для полного дампа замените `tables` на `full=Y`.

```
create table bigdata (key number, value varchar2(32), media blob);
/
-- добавил тестовую запись
select key, value, lengthb(media) mediasize from bigdata;

       KEY VALUE                             MEDIASIZE
---------- -------------------------------- ----------
         1 myvalue                             2048000

$  expdp sh1/sh1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=emptyblob.dmp tables=sh1.bigdata
. . exported "SH1"."BIGDATA"                             1.958 MB       1 rows
-- много

create or replace package remap as function rmblob(nul blob) return blob; end;
/
create or replace package body remap as 
    function rmblob(nul blob) return blob is begin return empty_blob(); end; end;
/

$  expdp sh1/sh1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=emptyblob.dmp tables=sh1.bigdata \
        remap_data=sh1.bigdata.media:sh1.remap.rmblob
. . exported "SH1"."BIGDATA"                             5.820 KB       1 rows

drop table bigdata;

$  impdp sh1/sh1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=emptyblob.dmp tables=sh1.bigdata
. . imported "SH1"."BIGDATA"                             5.820 KB       1 rows

       KEY VALUE                             MEDIASIZE
---------- -------------------------------- ----------
         1 myvalue                                   0
```