# Как копировать БД с уменьшенным объемом данных и сохранением связей по ключам?

Tags: sql, oracle

Eсть Oracle БД размером в несколько терабайт. Так же, в наличии есть пустая БД с аналогичной структурой (все таблицы пусты). Хочется получить копию большой БД с сильно уменьшенным объемом данных, ограничив его, например, до пары десятков гигабайт.

Основной объем занимают всего несколько таблиц, но есть большое количество ключей на них. Хочется забрать ограниченный объем данных не нарушая их согласованность.

Пока вижу решение используя линки:

1. Отключить все ключи, индексы, триггеры
2. Написать автогенератор, который сгенерирует код для перегрузки большей части данных из таблиц одной БД в другую. Всех таблиц не связанных ключами с тяжелыми таблицами.
3. В ручном режим дописать условия для остальных таблиц, чтобы загрузить только согласованные данные
4. Включить все ключи, индексы, триггеры

Существуют ли более простые и удобные способы решения задачи копирование уменьшенной копии БД?

Comment: Экономия планируется только за счет индексов? Или имеется в виду, что в больших таблицах есть ни с чем не связанные данные без которых можно обойтись?

Comment: @defaultlocale все еще грустнее. Есть куча связанных данных, которые хочется исключить при копировании, со всеми связями. Сотни тысяч отчетов, забрать из которых хочется лишь небольшой объем

Comment: Почему выбор упал на линки? Может лучше стандартные средства expdp/impdp. Тоже много настроек по чего/сколько /как.

Comment: Линки, первое что пришло мне в голову. Не понимаю, как решить задачу используя expdp

Comment: [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-oracle/598458#598458) не совсем ваша задача, но как пример,   как избавиться от clob.

Comment: @0xdb смотрел этот вопрос. К сожалению, так просто не получается. Надо сохранить согласованность данных

Comment: Только **как пример**, это не готовое решение. В чём вы видите проблему с согласованностью данных? Если надо исключить, пишете условие и данные не будут экспортированы.

Comment: @0xdb у меня набор связанных таблиц. Выгрузив по одной из них 10 миллионов строк вместо 10 миллиардов, я хочу чтобы по остальным таблицам выгрузилось только то, что есть в этой таблице. Не понимаю, как так сделать используя утилиты импорта. Какие слова гуглить?)

Comment: Попробуйте expdp tables query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачу можно решить с [Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump.html#GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A) экспортируя только часть данных, учитывая при этом  связи по ключам в условиях параметра [QUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-CDA1477D-4710-452A-ABA5-D29A0F3E3852).

Посмотрим пример для 100 заказов с такой структурой связанных таблиц:

```sql
create table items (id number primary key); 
create table orders (id number primary key, created date); 
create table orderitems (orderid number, itemid number, num number,
    constraint pkoi primary key (orderid, itemid),
    constraint fkor foreign key (orderid) references orders (id),
    constraint fkit foreign key (itemid) references items (id)); 
insert all
    when 1=1 then into items values (r)
    when m=0 then into orders values (o, add_months (date'2019-11-01',(o/10)-1))
    when 1=1 then into orderitems values (o, r, 1)
select rownum r, (ceil (rownum/10))*10 o, mod (rownum,10) m
from dual connect by level<=100;
```

Допустим, надо экспортировать только данные начиная с 2020 года. 
То есть, ожидается, что останется 8 заказов с 80-ю позициями. Для этого создадим файл с параметрами экспорта:

```
directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=orders20.dmp logfile=exporders20.log
schemas=iam
include=table:"in ('ITEMS','ORDERS','ORDERITEMS')"
query=orders:"where created>=date'2020-01-01'",
orderitems:"where orderid in (
    select id from orders where created>=date'2020-01-01')",
items:"where id in (
    select itemid from orderitems 
    where orderid in (select id from orders where created>=date'2020-01-01'))"
```

Создадим дамп экспорта:

```sh
$ expdp iam/pass@dbsrv/dbsvc parfile=exp20.par
```

Только для примера, чтобы не создавать новую БД/схему, удалим таблицы полностью:

```sql
drop table orderitems purge;
drop table items purge;
drop table orders purge;
```

В заключение импортируем данные:

```sh
impdp iam/pass@dbsrv/dbsvc directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=orders20.dmp logfile=imporders20.log
```

Результат как и ожидался, ограничения включены и валидированы:

```sql
select count (distinct orderid) orders, count (1) pos from orderitems;

    ORDERS        POS
---------- ----------
         8         80

select constraint_name, constraint_type, status, validated 
from user_constraints where table_name='ORDERITEMS'; 

CONSTR C STATUS   VALIDATED    
------ - -------- -------------
FKOR   R ENABLED  VALIDATED    
FKIT   R ENABLED  VALIDATED    
PKOI   P ENABLED  VALIDATED
```